# Erro de variáveis PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, delphi-7

Estou migrando uma aplicação de FireBird para PostgreSQL, consegui conectar o banco PostgreSQL com a ajuda da ferramenta Devart, porém agora sempre que tento  fazer algum acesso na aplicação está ocorrendo erro de formato da variável, segue um exemplo de erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Olhei em meu banco de dados PostgreSQL e essa opção de formato de variável `FMTBcdField` nem é disponível, se tiverem alguma ideia de mudando que possa fazer.

Consegui descobrir onde esta sendo determinado que o campo CODIGO deve ser FMTBcdField:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém quando tendo Deletar os fields para adicionar os novos já nos formatos corretos assim como foi sugerido, o seguinte erro ocorre:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por que motivos isso pode estar ocorrendo, já fiz o teste de colocar as *.dll citadas na pasta do exe e também na pasta System32, porém o erro persiste, será que há outro teste possível?

Tentei adicionar um SQLConnection junto para poder alterar o CLientDataSet, porém quando Deleto os fields e adiciono os novos fields quando vou salvar as alterações a seguinte mensagem de erro aparece:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém eu não encontro esse tal link para que possa editar as Fields

Comment: Meu amigo, assim como eu comentei lá na minha resposta, o Erro SQLConnection é porque esta faltando setar o Componente de Conexão nessa propriedade, Qual componente esta usando para DataSet?

Comment: Eu editei a pergunta para mostrar que há um link para a minha conexão, porém não encontro esse link para tentar ajustar a variável

Comment: Então meu caro, a solução que apresentei resolve seu problema, esse que você esta citando na ultima imagem não tem nada haver com o perguntado, Esse novo erro já é referente a outra `unit` do seu projeto! Ali ele diz `o DataModulo CadEmpresa citado no DataModulo Database não esta adicionado ao projeto! Deseja remover a referencia?` Apenas isto, adicione o dmCadEmpresa no projeto que deve parar o erro novo!

Comment: @JúniorMoreira Desculpa incomodar tanto, mas como disse sou novo em Delphi e pra ajudar esse projeto não é meu, você poderia me dar uma ajuda de como faço para adicionar o dmCadEmpresa ao projeto, pois pensei que o mesmo já estivesse adicionado

Comment: Shift + F11, procure a unit e abrir...

Comment: @JúniorMoreira Fiz o que você me pediu e apareceu o seguinte erro quando estava adicionando as fields novas em alguns ClientDataSet `Acess violation at address 00A55EED in module 'designide70.bpl'. Read of adress 0000001C.` Qual seria o motivo do erro tu saberia me dizer

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47517/discussion-between-r-santos-and-junior-moreira).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso geralmente é incompatibilidade de DLL (versão do DBExpress), procure a DLL `DBExpint` olhe a versão, troque por uma anterior (a do 6 funciona).

[Aqui](http://www.devmedia.com.br/forum/bcd-fmtbcdfield/39361) você pode encontrar mais uma solução que é desativar o BCD pelo BDE.

Se o Projeto não for muito grande você também pode remover os campos dos DataSets (Se for componente) e adiciona-los novamente! Assim o DataSet vai adicionar os Fields de acordo com o que o Provider fornecer.

Comment: Sou novo em Delphi, mas o projeto que estou mexendo é bem extenso, então como posso verificar esses campos DataSets, remove-los e adiciona-los novamente

Comment: Clique duplo no DataSet  (Se for componente)  que ele vai abrir todos os campos. Seleciona todos eles e Deleta, depois clica com Direito... Add All Fields...

Comment: Fiz isso que você comentou e apareceu o seguinte erro: `SQLConnection property required for this operation`

Comment: No caso citado o DataSet não possui uma conexão (ligado a um Componente de conexão). Veja se é o caso da DLL, ou leia o caso do BCD.

Comment: Acredito que não seja nenhum desses casos, fiz tudo que foi comentado porem o erro persiste, mas obrigado pela ajuda